# URL rewriting, using friendly urls

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently urls are like this http://example.com/?p=2, so if I link to another page in my site, it will be `<a href="http://example.com/?p=2"></a>`

A database contains a list of pages, with 3 columns, id, title and content. So for example the page with id `2` has a title of `foo`.

I want the user to be able to enter the url: http://example.com/foo and have the user see what is on http://example.com/?p=2. So I will be able to link to pages like: `<a href="http://example.com/foo"></a>` but the URL in the address bar will remain the friendly (`foo`) version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right syntax, but logically you should have in your .htaccess file something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?title=$1
```

then inside index.php you GET title and do what you want with it.

Comment: there is a problem that if I have a directory (eg bar) and type http://example.com/bar it append `/?titley=bar?` to the url resulting in `http://example.com/bar/?titley=bar?`

Comment: @Jonathan, you need a specific RewriteRule for each directory you have that should be publicly available. It's a bit of a hassle but that's the only method I'm aware of (what you're trying to accomplish is usually done as a built-in framework feature).